# Automatic JSON schema validation in Cloud9 IDE

Tags: cloud9-ide, cloud9, aws-cloud9

I have discovered that the real-time validation of JSON and YAML files in Visual Studio Code via [JSON Schema validators](https://json-schema.org/) is amazing and magical. However, I would like to migrate my project to [Cloud9 IDE](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/) (an offering from Amazon Web Services).  Is there a mechanism I can use to get similar schema validation of my files as I edit them in real-time, or at least periodically via a button click?

Perhaps if the desired functionality is not built-in I can throw something together with an AWS lambda function?